# ngx-translate: Translate strings in html

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

I am using ngx-translate lib to support I18N in my angular app.
Can anyone help me to mark the below html snippet for translation?

```
<span *ngIf="Days < 0 && !shortSentence">
      Follow-up is <span [class.font-bold]="highlightContent">{{ InDays | positiveNumber }} days</span> past due
    </span>
```

I want to mark only the text content within span tag. 
How can I make it as parametrized translations?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how you can use parametric translation with filters:

```
// define translation with parameter
'TRANSLATION_KEY': '{{days}} days'

// use it in template
<span>{{ 'TRANSLATION_KEY' | translate: { days: followUpInDays | positiveNumber } }}</span>
```

If you want to have the whole sentence as a translation (including the HTML), you will need to use `innerHTML` property binding:

```
// define translation with parameter
'TRANSLATION_KEY': 'Follow-up is <span class="{{className}}">{{days}} days</span> past due'

// use it in template
<span *ngIf="Days < 0 && !shortSentence"
      [innerHTML]="'TRANSLATION_KEY' | translate: { className: (highlightContent ? 'font-bold' : ''), days: followUpInDays | positiveNumber }">
</span>
```

Comment: I get the following output in UI: ""Follow-up is {days} days past due"". The expression {days} is not getting evaluated. How to solve this?

Comment: You need to use double curly brackets when defining the translation parameter (my bad, I use messageformat in the background so single curly brackets works too for me).

Comment: Apparently the innerHTML property does not work in IE11 - Obviously.... Microsoft and their broken browser.....